# Angular 2 and css animated floating bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Hi i'm currently writing an Angular 2 application and I wanted to create some kind of animated floating bubbles. I wanted it to work that way that there would be around 5-6 bubbles with an image inside that would randomly float around the screen. I don't care about the collision between them, I just want them to randomly float on the screen. I couldn't find any sample code for that in either Angular directive or pure css way. Could someone help me create that kind of animation?

Comment: This is a 3d javascript library - i just want a simple 2d animation of an image within a floating bubble.